# How can I pull Shopify customers and only get those that have a last name?

Tags: shopify-api

I currently pull the customers from Shopify by:

```
/admin/api/2023-10/customers.json?updated_at_min=xxxxx&limit=250
```

However, this pulls in ANY customer that was added, even if they've been added by a signup app, in which case they do not have a first or last name.
I want to filter those out, so I don't get those.

How do I do this? Can I add a check to see if last_name is filled? (not empty, not null, whatever)?